# Moment js not finding the time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am using angularJs and moment js. I have a textbox that sends for example

> 12:00 PM

to the function (apptime) - i then do

```
 var newtime = moment(apptime,'hh:mm:ss');
```

and this is what the console outputs :

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 12:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

so it is getting the time fine, i see 12:00:00 there..

then(because of the database structure) i want to convert it to this :

1899-12-30 12:00:00

so i do this :

```
console.log("1899-12-30 " + newtime.format('hh:mm:ss'));
```

and no matter what the date is, the response is always

> 1899-12-30 01:00:00

Why is it thinking 01 is the hour?

Comment: Could it be a daylight savings time issue?

Comment: No matter what time i input it returns the hour as 1, the mins work fine.

Comment: Weird, seems to work ok on in my console `"1899-12-30 " + moment('12:00 PM','hh:mm:ss').format('hh:mm:ss')` gives me `1899-12-30 12:00:00`

Comment: Works ok for me too (on Firefox), but I would say that the first format doesn't seem right to me. Your initial time isn't in the format specified in your initial format to moment. Shouldn't it be `var newtime = moment(apptime,'hh:mm a');`?

Answer (score 1):

It should convert to UTC time.

Change:

```
console.log("1899-12-30 " + newtime.format('hh:mm:ss'));
```

To:

```
console.log("1899-12-30 " + moment(newtime).utc().format('hh:mm:ss'));
```

Comment: Now its ouputting 12 no matter what time i enter

Comment: This gives you a different time from the time entered, depending on daylight savings time/timezone. Which is not necessarily what you want, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your input format to moment.js is incorrect.

```
var apptime = '12:00 PM';
var newtime = moment(apptime,'hh:mm a');
console.log(apptime);
console.log(newtime);
console.log("1899-12-30 " + newtime.format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

I also amended the output format to be military time, but you can amend that back to basic AM/PM, if you wish.